Flutter iOS Facebook Limited Login Bad Signature
Package version used:
flutter_facebook_auth: ^7.0.0
firebase_core: ^2.24.2
firebase_auth: ^4.15.2
FBSDKLoginKit (17.0.2) //pod

I have tested recently with our app and can't login with Facebook and upon debugging, I've seen this error
Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] {"code":190,"message":"Bad signature"}

Login attempt code:
Future<dynamic> signInWithFacebook() async {
  // try {
    final LoginResult loginResult = await _facebookAuth.login();

    if (loginResult.accessToken == null) {
      _hasError = true;
      _loginErrorMsg = 'Login cancelled.';
      notifyListeners();
      return null;
    }

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.tokenString);

    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}

The result of loginResult is LoginStatus.success.
Is someone experiencing the same issue? What are the steps have you done to resolve?

Thanks for the inputs, I'm able to solve my issue by doing the following.
In info.plist, add this
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>

Please take note that you have to update the privacy in App Store Connect.
For my Login Button
void facebookSignIn(BuildContext context) async {
  final authProvider = AuthServiceProvider();

  //since we only have the problem with iOS
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    TrackingStatus status =
        await AppTrackingTransparency.trackingAuthorizationStatus;

    if (status == TrackingStatus.notDetermined) {
      status = await AppTrackingTransparency.requestTrackingAuthorization();
    } else {
      if (status != TrackingStatus.authorized) {
        await openAppSettings();
      }
    }

    if (status != TrackingStatus.authorized) {
      Util.showSnackBar(
        context,
        'Login cancelled, to continue please allow this app to track your activity.',
      );
      return;
    }
  }

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized().addPostFrameCallback(
    (_) async {

      await authProvider.signInWithFacebook().then(
        (value) async {
          //handle the result here
        },
      );
    },
  );
}

and in my auth.dart
Future<dynamic> signInWithFacebook() async {
  try {
    final LoginResult loginResult = await _facebookAuth.login(
      loginTracking: LoginTracking.enabled,
    );

    if (loginResult.accessToken == null) {
      _hasError = true;
      _loginErrorMsg = 'Login cancelled.';
      notifyListeners();
      return null;
    }

    // Create a credential from the access token
    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.tokenString);

    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);

    return userCredential;
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    //FirebaseAuthException error handling
    return null;
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    //error handling
    notifyListeners();
    return null;
  }
}


I confirm this works. Yes it requires extra permissions for ios but works and fixes the bad signature error

I have the exact same problem and I followed these steps and still get the warning message about Limited Login.
Please take note that you have to update the privacy in App Store Connect.
Where do I do this?

I have the same issue, below code works for me.
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithFacebook(BuildContext context) async {
  final rawNonce = generateNonce();
  final nonce = sha256ofString(rawNonce);
  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance
      .login(
    loginTracking: LoginTracking.limited,
    nonce: nonce,
  )
      .catchError((onError) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      //print(onError);
    }
    throw Exception(onError.message);
  });

  if (loginResult.accessToken == null) {
    throw Exception(loginResult.message);
  }
  // Create a credential from the access token
  OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential;

  print("tokenType${loginResult.accessToken!.type}");

  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    switch (loginResult.accessToken!.type) {
      case AccessTokenType.classic:
        final token = loginResult.accessToken as ClassicToken;
        facebookAuthCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
          token.authenticationToken!,
        );
        break;
      case AccessTokenType.limited:
        final token = loginResult.accessToken as LimitedToken;
        facebookAuthCredential = OAuthCredential(
          providerId: 'facebook.com',
          signInMethod: 'oauth',
          idToken: token.tokenString,
          rawNonce: rawNonce,
        );
        break;
    }
  } else {
    facebookAuthCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      loginResult.accessToken!.tokenString,
    );
  }

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}

Generates a cryptographically secure random nonce, to be included in a
credential request.
  String generateNonce([int length = 32]) {
    const charset =
        '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._';
    final random = Random.secure();
    return List.generate(length, (_) => charset[random.nextInt(charset.length)])
        .join();
  }

  /// Returns the sha256 hash of [input] in hex notation.
  String sha256ofString(String input) {
    final bytes = utf8.encode(input);
    final digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
    return digest.toString();
  }


hi @vijay I've tried using this but upon testing, it only works in simulators, but not in actual device. Am I missing something? Thanks ..

value of loginResult.accessToken is always null on physical device but in simulator, it works well. Do you happen to know what could be the cause?

This seems to fix the problem for me... don't understand what is going on though.

The credentials used to authenticate the Admin SDKs cannot be used to perform the desired action. Certain Authentication methods such as createCustomToken() and verifyIdToken() require the SDK to be initialized with a certificate credential as opposed to a refresh token or Application Default credential. See Initialize the SDK for documentation on how to authenticate the Admin SDKs with a certificate credential.
For iOS
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>FacebookClientToken</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>xxxxxxxxx</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
         <string>sms</string>
         <string>tel</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
 <true/>


Hi. Thanks for this but the above code works in android and my only concern is the iOS.

Hi @ramedju, have you added the necessary information in info.plist file?

Hi @ramedju, I've updated the answer pls add that code in iOS side and do let me know if it's working or not

hi @Dhruvan, I already have that settings. All is going well and just yesterday, the error is persisting.
